# Getting OnLongClick to work in ListView Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am currently trying to get `onLongClick` on each item of my listview but android studio will not recognise `super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);` and `super.onContextItemSelected(item);`. When I take these out noting works at all.

Inside onCreate I have

```
registerForContextMenu(getListView());
```

Then below this function I have the following functions

```
 public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
                         super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
                         AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
                         menu.setHeaderTitle(mAdapter.getItem(info.position).toString());
                         menu.add(Menu.NONE, CONTEXT_MENU_DELETE, CONTEXT_MENU_DELETE, R.string.del_item);
                     }



             public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case CONTEXT_MENU_DELETE:
                                mAdapter.remove(info.position);
                                return true;
                            default:
                            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
```

Comment: Make sure your imports are proper android.app.Activity.onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item);

Comment: @piyush The imports that are supposed to be used for this are saying they are not currently being used, why is this?

Comment: yes i know that is why i have given full path to check.Since eclipse is not giving problem it recognises your code just as is.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the imports are from the compatibility library and not from the SDK itself.

Comment: How do I make sure of this?

Comment: Try this,Since i think its an import problem.if studio do not recognises the method.

Comment: Yes it does not know the method so what do I change?